# Bootstrap search bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Simple question or maybe not heh. So i've implemented the Bootstrap search function to my nav, although how do I get it to actually search things ony my app?

In other-words, how do I get to generate search results? For the time being it is just eye-candy that doesn't function what so ever.

```
<form class="navbar-search">
<input type="text" class="search-query span3" placeholder="search">
</form>
```

Comment: You probably want to hire a web developer.

Comment: Dont ask  Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)
    Product or service recommendations or comparisons
    Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
    Anything not directly related to writing computer programs

Answer (score 1):

The search bar that bootstrap provides is just a nice looking search bar, it doesn't come with any search functionality built in or linked to it.

To perform a search you'd have to create a search method yourself which you can call from the search form as you would any other HTML form, passing a search query and then redirecting to a page of results. If you don't want to redirect you could use ajax of course.

Either way, it's not going to be the super quick easy search you might be anticipating!